# Xapo bitcoin transaction stuck

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

ive been using bitcoin since early 2013 and yesterday my transaction got "stuck" when trying to send some bitcoin to my Xapo wallet, this has never happened to me before.

im kind of scared that i can lose this 250$, any help/information would be nice :)

heres the transaction: https://insight.bitpay.com/tx/ce5a327293c4f4b046bc7e1ab5ee9f06ecbdf4da37e78c75a506627d6ecd12d7

Comment: Transaction was confirmed 94 blocks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you send the bitcoins from? Anyways, due to the many unconfirmed bitcoin transactions in the network right now, your fee is relatively low and it therefore takes so long to confirm. If you did send them from a wallet you control, then you can try to use RBF or double-spend it with a higher fee. Otherwise contact the sender of the bitcoins, or wait some more time for it to confirm.

See also here:
[Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and thats the thing i got it sent from service where i cashed out so its my money but not from a wallet i control. is there possibilty i lose my money?

Comment: If the service provider is a business then it should not become a problem, since in the rare case that the transaction is dropped from the network due to too long waiting time, you can contact the service provider and they can easily verify that the bitcoins were indeed not sent. In general, the bitcoins are first yours when the transaction is confirmed in the blockchain.